# MySql Query Speed Confusion BETWEEN or many index queries

Tags: mysql, indexing, comparison

I've got a situation where i have to select some rows from a table....

The table is somewhat as follows.......

```
        id           Name          Age

        0011         name1          45
        0012         name2          67
        .
        . 
        .
        .
        0020         name10         100
        .
        .
        .
        .


         // id is a primary key varchar(4).......
         // name is varchar.....
         // age is int.......
```

Now my need is to get values within a range like `0011 - 0020` or `0020 - 0030`.....
I can generate the start and end of this paricular range which i would like you not to think about......

But the doubt i've got is

```
          Should I execute 10 SELECT queries based on the index values ?
```

for eg:-

```
           for(i=0;i<10;i++)
           {
                    //SQL Query to SELECT row WHERE id = '0011' LIMIT 0,1 
                    // next time it id to select would be '0012'
            }
```

***OR***

```
           Should I include a single Query to SELECT ROWS using AND, OR , BETWEEN..etc..with limit 10..???
```

Which one is faster....???

I've got confusion coz in the first case, **only 1 row is selected at a time** and **without much of a operation in each query** (where **10 times request is the villain**) and in second case where only **one** query is used, But i believe an overhead is provided on the varchar primary key using comparison operators........

Comment: As they're both quick to implement, perhaps you should do so and benchmark them to get an indication?

Answer (score 1):

The real cost is parsing and executing multiple queries versus getting more data than you need now, or may need now.

Given you appear to be paging, as in getting ten at a time, you should be seletinga  page full at once with a between.

Sometimes a query optimiser may do better with `>= Start and <= End` than `between start and end`, but other than that I can't see an issue, unless your table was extremely wide (lot's of data in one row)

Comment: @akp You would require both `between` and `limit` for pagination.

Comment: @Ravinder so i presume u are opting to use the second condition using LIMIT constraint...

Comment: @akp Yes. Use `between` to select records in a range and use `limit` for pagination.

Comment: @akp . Yep pagination is a standard, how complex it has to be depends on your data (e.g. can you insert before it), if you delet one on the page will arecord be skipped on next page etc. But it's all well understood logic.

Answer (score 0):

Single Query is faster way to fetch data from database comparison to other query with for loop they take so much time because each query has own individual execution time now it up to which way you have choose

Comment: see i 've got to get 10 rows ..but the confusion i've got is will it make the query operation slower if i used the comparison operators like `>=, <=` etc..

Comment: These operators are not responsible for slower @akp

Comment: i mean it's like selecting stuffs from with some pre condition won't be a overhead.....sorry..if i m being stupid about this question...

Answer (score 0):

You can do sql query to return the results of a table SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table, for example: 1000 
And get number of pages $pages=ceil(1000/10);

```
for ($i=0;$i<=$pages:$i++) {
$start=10*$i;
$sql="SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM TABLE WHERE LIMIT ".$start.",10";
}
```